# finding a specific split string in CSV file [Python]

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, opencsv

I have a file with peoples information, including date of birth, and want to be able to call the month out of dd/mm/yyyy format to find the persons name from thir month of birth. So far i  have this:

```
def DOBSearch():
    DOBsrch = int(input("Please enter the birth month: "))
    for row in BkRdr:
        DOB = row[6]
        day,month,year = DOB.split("/")
        if DOB == month: 
            surname = row[0]
            firstname = row[1]
            print(firstname, " ",surname)
            addrsBk.close
```

But it returns

```
Please enter the birth month: 02
#(nothing is printed)
```

Comment: `if DOBsrch == month:`????

Comment: that is corrext thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare `ints` with `ints` or `strs` with `strs`.
`DOBsrch` is an `int`, but `DOB` is probably a `str` (since you use its `split` method).

So you need

```
day,month,year = map(int, DOB.split("/"))
```

or, at least

```
day,month,year = DOB.split("/")
month = int(month)
```

---

Also, as @devnull points out, you probably want to compare the `month` with `DOBsrch`, not `DOB`:

```
if DOBsrch == month:
```

Comment: It seems that the OP wants `if DOBsrch == month:` instead.